# worklight http adapter and NTLM authentication

Tags: authentication, adapter, ntlm, ibm-mobilefirst

i'm trying to implement NTLM authentication in a Worklight HTTP Adapter in order to connect to M$ back-end servers, such as Sharepoint Web services.
i've set-up my adapter.xml file with <ntlm>.

The adapter.xml structure first version was:

```
<authentication>
  <ntlm />
  <serverIdentity>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </serverIdentity>
</authentication>
```

My tests are done locally with Worklight studio, i get the following issues:

1) error when invocating WL procedure:

```
Procedure invocation failed:Could not resolve placeholder 'local.hostname'
```

where do i have to put this 'local.hostname' setting?

2) i tried to specifiy the hostname property of ntlm tag as given in documentation (IBM infocenter), WL Studio says that the xml is bad formed.

```
<authentication>
  <ntlm hostname="myComputer.intranet.com"/>
  <serverIdentity>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>password</password>
  </serverIdentity>
</authentication>
```

Where "myComputer.intranet.com" is my computer's name within my corporate network.

```
Attribute 'hostname' is not allowed to appear in element 'ntlm'
```

Answer (score -1):

Response from IBM Service Request:
The username used to authenticate with NTLM-enabled back-end system must be left padded with the windows domain name followed by a \, and the username.

```
<serverIdentity>
  <username>domain\user</username>
  <password>password</password>
</serverIdentity>
```

This works with hard-coded serverIdentity feature.

Due to security governance in my company, there can't be "generic" server identity. So i have to forward the end users' credentials to back-end systems to authenticate.

How to do this with Worklight authentication mecanisms (adapter-based for instance), where can i set the domain for my username?
Can i mix several kinds of security realms depending on adapters?